# Get access to Stackoverflow's auto-suggest tagging system?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, stackexchange-api

Is there anyway to get access to stackoverflow's awesome tagging system? I would like to borrow Stack's awesome auto-suggest and tag mini-explanation boxes for my own site. Obviously, I can use the jQuery UI auto-suggest for tags but I would really like to also include the cool little tag descriptions as well. If not, can someone tell me where all these explanation/descriptions came from so that I can implement a similar system? [image]

Comment: The code is here: `view-source:http://stackoverflow.com/`.

Comment: Yeah, but I don't want to hotlink or rip them off without permission.

Comment: Then you should probably contact them directly rather than in a question.

Comment: Well, it seemed something that would be interesting to lots of other folks, so I thought I would leave it open. Judging from the number of up-votes this got in such a short amount of time, it seems like it must be on other peoples' minds as well.

Comment: @Thomas - You might want to look at the `StackExchange` object. (in the console, type `window.StackExchange`)

Comment: wouldn't this be a more appropriate question for [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/)?

Comment: @philipvr: seems like a "proper" dev question - but that's just an imo

Comment: Yeah, it seemed like a grey-area to me. But more people look at stack so thats why I went that way.

Comment: @Thomas - See my answer, figured out how the api works.

Comment: @philipvr: Just because it mentions Stack Overflow doesn't mean it goes to meta.

Comment: +1 for caring about permissions even though others suggest not to.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[tageditornew.js](http://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/tageditornew.en.js)

Line 308:

```
$.get("/filter/tags", {q: a,newstyle: !0}, "json").done(function(c) {
    C["t_" + a] = c;
    StackExchange.helpers.removeSpinner();
    b(c)
})
```

This might help you out!

---

## It turns out that,

the API url is this:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/filter/tags?q=STRING&newstyle=BOOLEAN
```

- **`q`**  - Query text.
- **`newstyle`**  - Require new style or not. Result in new style will be returned in JSON with additional information such as synonyms and excerpt.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/bXXb7/ (with Cross Domain Requests jQuery plguin)

For example:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/filter/tags?q=htm
```

would give you:

```
"html|99829\nhtml5|16359\nxhtml|4143\nhtml-parsing|1461\nhtml-lists|1328\nhtml5-video|949"
```

where `99829` is the amount of questions. It took me 15 minutes looking at the source code to find out this api. -_-"

Putting in `javascript` in new style gives you this: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/filter/tags?q=javascript&newstyle=true)

> <sub>`[{"Name":"javascript","Synonyms":"classic-javascript|javascript-execution","Count":223223,"Excerpt":"JavaScript is a dynamic language commonly used for scripting in web browsers. It is NOT the same as Java. Use this tag for questions regarding ECMAScript and its dialects/implementations (excluding ActionScript and JScript). If a framework or library, such as jQuery, is used, include that tag as well. Questions that don't include a framework/library tag, such as jQuery, implies that the question requires a pure JavaScript answer."},{"Name":"javascript-events","Synonyms":"javascript-event","Count":5707,"Excerpt":"Creating and handling JavaScript events inline in HTML or through a script."},{"Name":"facebook-javascript-sdk","Synonyms":"","Count":992,"Excerpt":"Facebook's JavaScript SDK provides a rich set of client-side functionality for accessing Facebook's server-side API calls. These include all of the features of the REST API, Graph API, and Dialogs."},{"Name":"javascript-library","Synonyms":"","Count":675,"Excerpt":"A JavaScript library is a library of pre-written JavaScript which allows for easier development of JavaScript-based applications, especially for AJAX and other web-centric technologies."},{"Name":"javascript-framework","Synonyms":"","Count":563,"Excerpt":"A JavaScript framework is a library of pre-written JavaScript which allows for easier development of JavaScript-based applications, especially for AJAX and other web-centric technologies."},{"Name":"unobtrusive-javascript","Synonyms":"","Count":340,"Excerpt":"Unobtrusive JavaScript is a general approach to the use of JavaScript in web pages."}]`</sub>

What you can get from there:

- All tags start with `javascript`
- Synonyms
- Tag counts
- Nice tag descriptions

Comment: I think so, I just need to try and implement it to see if there are any cross-server issues with calling it. Otherwise, if I can use it to build similar auto-suggest boxes with the same supplemental content - it will be just what I was looking for.

Comment: It should be fine if you use PHP. By the way, may I have an upvote? :)

Comment: You already got mine... If I had another, I'd give it to you.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for high-level logic, in a nutshell it's just a custom auto-complete that's blazing-fast.

Whenever you type a tag (i.e. a new word or one separated by a space from previous tags), an AJAX request would be made to the server with a JSON object which is then interpreted by the client-side script and presented in the usable layout.

Comparing the autocomplete JSON objects for [letter "h"](https://stackoverflow.com/filter/tags?q=h&newstyle=true) and [word "html"](https://stackoverflow.com/filter/tags?q=html&newstyle=true) should give you enough insight into how this particular implementation works (if prompted, these can be opened with any text editor).

On a somewhat unrelated note: the autocomplete responses have to be *fast*. Depending on the complexity of the data autocomplete is run against, you may find [how IMDb magic search works](http://aws.amazon.com/de/solutions/case-studies/imdb/) intriguing.

### Update:

Seeing your comment about accessing the *content* of the tag library, this may in fact be more of a meta question. I struggle to think of a scenario where using an API if any or just the tag library from an external resource would be beneficial to SO - however content here is provided under Creative Commons so you *may* be able to use it with proper attribution. This does not constitute legal advice :)

Comment: I understand how the guts work. I guess I am really interested in the library of descriptions and tags they have. There are thousands and I have a hard time believing that they paid anyone to write and curiate those individually, so I want to figure out where I can get access to the same library. If they did originate with stack, I'd love to get an api or something to pull them into my own site.

Comment: @Thomas: Those snippets are from the [tag wikis](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/html/info) which are [managed by Stack Overflow users](http://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/2).